# How to use make BarCheckItem IsCheked trigger a style change in the BarCheckItem's DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml

#### The Problem: In BarCheckItem, if BarCheckItem IsChecked, how do I style a border inside its DataTemplate?

I'm styling a `BarCheckItem`. To do it, I added a `ContentTemplate` with a                                `DataTemplate` inside where I added some color borders that change on MouseOver:

```
<dxb:BarCheckItem Name="barCheckItemRecord"
                  Command="..."
                  Cursor="Hand"
                  IsChecked="..."
                  IsVisible="..." >

      <dxb:BarCheckItem.ContentTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel>
                      <Border x:Name="audioButtonInnerBorderLight">
                          <Canvas .../>
                      </Border>
                  </StackPanel>

                  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                             <Setter TargetName="audioButtonInnerBorderLight" Property="Background" Value="#30FFFFFF" />
                       </Trigger>
                  </DataTemplate.Triggers>

           </DataTemplate>
       </dxb:BarCheckItem.ContentTemplate>
</dxb:BarCheckItem>
```

What I want to do now is to **change the color of the border** when the BarCheckItem is `IsChecked`.

Problem is, I only know how to use the triggers in a style, like this:

```
<dxb:BarCheckItem Name="barCheckItemRecord" [all the code from above]>
...
<dxb:BarCheckItem.Style>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type dxb:BarCheckItem}">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                 <Style.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                       </Trigger>
                       <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                       </Trigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
</dxb:BarCheckItem.Style>
</dxb:BarCheckItem>
```

**But I don't know how to point to  the border (x:Name="audioButtonInnerBorderLight") FROM the triggers. Because the triggers don't know where the border is.**

How can I make something like the following work?:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dxb:BarCheckItem}">
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
     <Setter TargetName="audioButtonInnerBorderLight" Property="Background" Value="Purple" />
</Trigger>
</Style>
```

Note: I thought the best idea was to put the border in a ContentTemplate in the `BarCheckItem`, using a `Template` setter. But it looks like BarCheckItems don't allow Templating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the best way to do this.

What I did was adding the ContentTemplate in the styles, and use the triggers from there:

```
<dxb:BarCheckItem ...>

     <dxb:BarCheckItem.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type dxb:BarCheckItem}">
             <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                 <Setter.Value>
                     <DataTemplate>
                          <StackPanel>
                              <Border x:Name="audioButtonInnerBorderLight">
                                  <Canvas .../>
                              </Border>
                          </StackPanel>

                          <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                   <Setter TargetName="audioButtonInnerBorderDark" Property="Background" Value="#30FFFFFF" />
                              </Trigger>
                          </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                      </DataTemplate>
                   </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>

               <Style.Triggers>
                   <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                       <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                           <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                     <StackPanel>
                                          <Border x:Name="audioButtonInnerBorderCHECKED">
                                               <Canvas .../> (different styles here)
                                          </Border>
                                     </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                       </Setter>
                   </Trigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </dxb:BarCheckItem.Style>
 </dxb:BarCheckItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

You sholud add those triggers to the DataTemplate :

```
  <dxb:BarCheckItem Name="barCheckItemRecord"
              Command="..."
              Cursor="Hand"
              IsChecked="..."
              IsVisible="..." >

        <dxb:BarCheckItem.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border x:Name="audioButtonInnerBorderLight">
                        <Canvas .../>
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>

                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="audioButtonInnerBorderLight" Property="Background" Value="#30FFFFFF" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dxb:BarCheckItem}}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="audioButtonInnerBorderLight" Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsChecked,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dxb:BarCheckItem}}}"  Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="audioButtonInnerBorderLight" Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>

            </DataTemplate>
        </dxb:BarCheckItem.ContentTemplate>
    </dxb:BarCheckItem>
```

Comment: I tried with these bindings, but it looks like the dxb:BarCheckItem is not the parent, but the element itself. I figured out it'd be better to include the ContentTemplate in the styles, so I'll that as an answer. Thank you for the suggestion, though.