# how to use default checkbox icon in WPF?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, ribbon-control

I want to use the default checkbox icon in ribbonpage.barcheckitem, i can set its Glyph attribute to set its image, but i want to use the default checkbox icon, i thought if i don't set the Glyph attribute,it will use default checkbox icon as its style, but the result is no icon showed, so i want to know what is the image url of default checkbox icon,so i can use this like:

```
<dxb:BarCheckItem Glyph="pack://application:,,,/Resources/img/ui/view.png"/>
```

Just use its image url to replace the Glyph value.

Anyone knows can help me solve this problem,thanks!

Comment: What is `dxb:BarCheckItem`?

Comment: @Dai, it's a item like checkbox, but can be used with RibbonControl.
xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"

Answer (score 0):

The Following page will help you ,

I Think use style that`s the point :

Visit [How to use make BarCheckItem IsCheked trigger a style change in the BarCheckItem's DataTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804998/how-to-use-make-barcheckitem-ischeked-trigger-a-style-change-in-the-barcheckitem)